# Pocket book size for novel (10.8 x 17.5 cm)

Tags: memoir, paper-size

Since a time I only use LaTeX for my writing requirements, for maths, histories, scripts, but this time I want to send a novel to a service like bubok or lulu or whatever that prints books to have it on my hands.

But it wasn't too easy at all, because I want to publish in a pocket book format (because of the book is about 50 pages, a short story) like I said in the topic (10.8 x 17.5 cm) and I spent few days looking for a configuration of the page size for `memoir` class, and my search is becoming a failure. So I decided to write here expecting some help for my madness idea.

Comment: You can use `\setstocksize{175mm}{108mm}`

Comment: Try the `geometry` package.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I think `\setstocksize` is preferable with `memoir`

Comment: @Still, Maybe you want the `foolscapvopaper` paper size (6.75in x 4.25in), then you can use `\documentclass[foolscapvopaper]{memoir}`.

Answer (score 10):

The `memoir` class has its own set of macros for fixing the page layout, which differs from those of the `geometry` package.

The class has several pre-defined paper sizes, such as `a4paper`, `letterpaper` and `b5paper`. You can find them all (and what they mean) in the [memoir manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf). They are used as follows

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
```

If you are not satisfied by the pre-defined sizes, then you can choose something different

```
\setstocksize{<height>}{<width>}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
```

You could have something like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\setstocksize{17.5cm}{10.8cm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.2cm}{1.2cm}{*} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{1.2cm}{1.2cm}{*}  % Upper and lower margin
\checkandfixthelayout 

\begin{document}

An awesome story...

\end{document}
```